# How do you define the fluctuation of energy in the canonical ensemble?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I read that the fluctuation in energy is given by $$ \delta E = E  - \langle E\rangle  $$

But I don't quite get this. Is this only over one particle? So is E the definite energy of the particle?  The last term is of course the average energy so I suppose this is indeed the fluctuation in energy, but how would you generalize this for a system of N particles, and how would you choose E then?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fluctuations are generally characterized as a deviation from average. That is, for quantity $Q$ one defines its fluctuation as
$$\delta Q = Q - \langle Q\rangle,$$
where $\langle Q\rangle$ is the average. with such definition one obviously has $\langle \delta Q\rangle = $, so one uses either fluctuation squared or the mean absolute deviation to characterize the level of fluctiations
$$\sigma_Q^2 = \langle(\delta Q)^2\rangle = \langle Q^2\rangle - \langle Q\rangle^2,\\
MAD = \langle |\delta Q|\rangle.$$

Finally, the fluctuation of energy can be calculated as for a single particle, as well as for the whole system - depending on what $E$ represents in yoru question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I've one other question :). Suppose I want to calculate the fluctuation squared for N particles. When calculating <Q>^2, do I square the average energy of the whole system, or do I square the average of one particle and multiply it by N? The difference is, I think, that the first will end up with N^2 while the second will end up with N. Thanks!

Comment: You use the same quantity for $\langle E^2\rangle$ and $\langle E\rangle^2$ - i.e. both either the total energy or the energy per particle.